# Testing performance of APIs that include several steps

Tags: performance, api, rest, testing, performance-testing

I want to test the performance of a REST API while simulating the actions performed by a user in the GUI. It needs to be able to perform a total of 4 requests in sequence, where request 2, 3 and 4 is based on information received in the first request (getting IDs, locations, etc, and then using those in request 2,3 and 4), and then store the results from each request.

Is there any testing frameworks that are capable of performing such actions programatically? Preferably based on JAVA, but not necessarily. I'm planning to run this for an estimation of 30 users. Any tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The most popular Java-based test framework is [REST-assured](https://rest-assured.io/), for multithreading you can use either [ExecutorService](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial) or [Java Microbenchmark Harness](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Alternatively you can go for a load testing tool, the most popular of the Java-based ones are:

- [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) - where you can create API tests using GUI, see [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) for details
- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) - it's in Scala but runs in JVM, see [API Load Testing With Gatling](https://dzone.com/articles/api-load-testing-with-gatling) to get started